# Dedicated Executor stops working after a certain amount of submitted threads

Tags: java, spring, completable-future, threadpoolexecutor

I have this 2 pieces of code:

1.

```java
    @Override
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<List<Activity>> findAllAndMakeAFuture() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            log.info("Current thread: {}", Thread.currentThread());
            return activityRepository.findsAll();
        });
    }
```

2. 

```java
    @Override
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<List<Activity>> findAllAndMakeAFutureWithDedicatedExecutor(Executor executor) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            log.info("Current thread: {}", Thread.currentThread());
            return activityRepository.findsAll();
        }, executor);
    }
```

I have this dedicated `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`

```java
@Bean
Executor executor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(48);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(48);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10000);
}
```

I have an Apache jMeter Test where i query http endpoints for the code in 1. and 2.

When i use 200 threads in jMeter for code 1., everything works fine.

When i use the same query for code 2., at some point my application stops working without giving an exception.

When i lower the threads from 200 to 100 code 1. and 2. works.

It seems that the usage of my dedicated `Executor` stops working.

Do you know any limitations of using dedicated `Executors`?

When i use this as my dedicated executor - even code 2. runs without any issue: `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`

**Edit:**

Stop working means there are no logger outputs. With every call to `activityRepository.findsAll()` i´ll do a log output how much time it takes to fetch the data. This output is not there anymore.

Furthermore Apache jMeter does not stop automatically the query.

I didn´t do any further investigation (like thread dump) cause i can say that the issue has something to do with exclusive usage of the dedicated `Executor` bean in code 2.

Comment: What does "stops working" mean? What does a thread dump tell you?

Comment: I´ve added two flags to my `Executor`: `threadPoolTaskExecutor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);`
  `threadPoolTaskExecutor.setDaemon(true);` It seems that this does the job ... I will investigate further

Comment: Why are you passing in the executor instead of wiring it into the class? Another thing is that if you are using this with Spring Boot this will also be used for handling web requests (the async part) so you are now filling it up twice as fast as before (Spring Boot starts a default executor but you ahve overridden that now).

Comment: @M.Deinum You´re right. This needs polish (Autowiring the executor). What i wanted to check is if there are performance gains while using a dedicated Executor as stated here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor or going with the integrated one. As for now i cannot measure any gain in using the dedicated one.

Comment: Because you now have 1 executor that is used for 2 things (Spring MVC Async **and** kicking of tasks), in the first sample you have 2 (1 used by the Spring MVC async support and one for doing the tasks) instead of 1. Not counting the one from Tomcat that is. Also don't use deamon threads use regular ones.